# Tracking Widgets using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have this widget code that i wish to track via GA analytics without changing the code structure. how can i do this using GA event tracking feature.

the widget code is as below:

```
<script src="http://widgets.unnamed.co.ke/21/index.php?source=mysite"     type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You should provide the code of what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

We've added google analytics code to the widget javascript. Note that you need to make some adjustments when the GA code is inside a function in your code. e.g:

```
var g = window._gaq || (window._gaq = []);
g.push(['some_unique_name._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
```

In addition you have to make sure your GA doesn't interfere with the site's GA. So you need to make sure that the domain (and some other definitions) is set to the same domain as the site's GA definitions. You also should make sure to use your own tracker.